# how to sum price column to another total column use oracle sql select statement?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

May i know how to use sum price column base on invoice_no and total up in total_amount column and
the total_amount value for each row is always be the sum of the each invoice_no. (eg invoice_no 10001 total_amount is 150.00)

```
table_a

invoice_no.   items            price   qty 
10001         apple             50.00   1
10001         papaya           100.00   1
10002         water melon       50.00   1
10002         orange            50.00   1
```

my query

```
select invoice_no,items,price,qty from (select invoice_no,items,price,qty from table_a where invoice_no='10001' union all
select null,null,null,sum(price) from table_a where invoice_no='10001') table_a;
```

my output

```
invoice_no.   items            price   qty 
10001         apple             50.00   1
10001         papaya           100.00   1
                               150.00
```

correct result

```
invoice_no.   items        total_amount      price   qty 
10001         apple           150.00          50.00   1
10001         papaya          150.00         100.00   1
10002         water melon     100.00          50.00   1
10002         orange          100.00          50.00   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `SUM()` here as analytic function:

```sql
SELECT
    invoice_no,
    items,
    SUM(price) OVER (PARTITION BY invoice_no) AS total_amount,
    price,
    qty
FROM table_a;
```